# Trying to use a plain js function to rotate and scaleX at the same time with a variable for the degrees of rotation

Tags: javascript, css-transforms

Trying to use plain js function call to rotate a DIV a variable number of degrees and x flip  the DIV  at same time.
Really having trouble formatting the command.

This works to rotate with  a variable

```
var rot=45;//number of degrees
divTag.style.transform="rotate(" +rot + "deg)";
```

This will transform x axis but wipes out the rotate

```
var rot=45;//number of degrees
divTag.style.transform="rotate(" +rot + "deg)";
transform:"scaleX(-1)";
```

Trying to combine the two commands into form:
transform: rotate() scaleX() having trouble to get proper strings and quotes positioning;

Have tried many variations such as the following

```
var rot=45;//number of degrees
divTag.style.transform='scaleX(-1) rotate(" +rot + "deg)"';
```

Can someone please give me proper syntax for the above?

Answer (score 0):

OK I think I got it!!!

divTag.style.transform="scaleX(-1) rotate(" +rot + "deg)";